# Using glReadPixels for reading pixel data of a texture image

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Can you use glReadPixels to read pixel data from a texture image?

My code for generating a texture image is:

```
gl.glTexImage2D( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL2.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap( pixels ) );
```

The variable pixels contain the pixel values of an image. Then I use glReadPixels to try to read the pixel data of the texture image just created.
My code for using glReadPixels is:

```
    FloatBuffer buffer = FloatBuffer.allocate( 4 );
    for ( int row = 0, col; row < height; row++ ) {
        for ( col = 0; col < width; col++ ) {
            gl.glReadPixels( col, row, 0, 0, GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_FLOAT, buffer );
            System.out.print( buffer.get( 0 ) );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The problem is I keep getting a value of 0.0,
I'm wondering if the texture image is stored in the framebuffer since glReadPixels read data from the framebuffer?

Answer (score 5):

glReadPixels reads from the default framebuffer (GL_BACK for dbl buffering), yes.
To read a texture, you may want to use FBO w/ attached texture colorbuffer.
Then set the FBO active and you can use glReadPixels.
Since FBO is pretty complicated to tame and you are using JOGL, 
I link you to an [offscreen unit test](http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl.git;a=blob;f=src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/acore/TestFBOOnThreadSharedContext1DemoES2NEWT.java;hb=HEAD) which uses GLFBODrawable/FBObject
internally and uses glReadPixels to perform the snapshot.
Ofc .. you would need to walk a bit through the code and it's new API.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error in this line.

```
gl.glReadPixels( col, row, 0, 0, GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_FLOAT, buffer );
```

Try the following instead

```
gl.glReadPixels( col, row, 1, 1, GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_FLOAT, buffer );
```

Also it's better to read the whole image at the same time. Do not forget to allocate needed buffer size.

```
gl.glReadPixels( col, row, width, height, GL2.GL_RGBA, GL2.GL_FLOAT, buffer );
```